# shell_exec Not Working with with "composer self-update"

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, composer-php, apache2, raspbian

I am trying to run

```
shell_exec('composer self-update');
```

but it will not output anything when visiting a page that has that with apache2. When I use the same file with the PHP CLI it works and returns I have the latest version. `shell_exec` and `exec` are not on my disabled functions, and I have used

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to see if it returns anything and it does not. Putting the `shell_exec` output in a variable and dumping the variable returns `NULL`. I am using Apache/2.4.38 on Raspberry Pi OS Buster (formerly Raspbian) with PHP 7.3-fpm.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626218/composer-phar-dont-want-to-run-by-shell-exec-from-php-script-why

Comment: The issue is that it writes the messages to standard error, not standard output.